# php translation

Tags: php, localization, gettext

Ok, I'm losing my mind here...
I have a webpage and i need to translate it. To test the translation I set up a helloworld-type file to test it, and then I applied the code to the whole page when I was finished. So:

i have a file test.php and it contains:

```
<?php
$directory = dirname(__FILE__).'/l';
$domain = 'mydomain';
$locale ="hr_HR";

putenv("LANG=".$locale);

setlocale( LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain($domain, $directory);
textdomain($domain);
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');
echo _("Hello World"); 
?>
```

The file is located in the `d:\xampp\htdocs\` folder

i have a file hr_HR.po and it contains:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#. Text in function
#: test.php:8
msgid "Hello World"
msgstr "TEST"
```

and it's located in the `d:\xampp\htdocs\l\hr_HR\` folder.

Using *poedit* i was able to make a .mo file out of the .po file...

So everything should be working fine, but it isn't... any help would be appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My highly subjective opinion is that gettext() stinks. I recommend [`Zend_Translate`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html) instead

Comment: @Pekka: Zend_Translate is not an 'instead' for gettext(), it's just a generic wrapper for many different translation technologies among others gettext. Zend_Translate with gettext works really well!

Comment: Where are you telling gettext about the path to hr_HR.mo ?

Comment: @markus Zend_Translate can work with gettext *files* which is great, but it is much easier to handle locale-wise than PHP's built-in gettext functions - you don't have to find out which exact locale code that happens to be installed on the OS (which is why I hate native gettext with a passion)

Comment: well.. nowhere.. i was using [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) tutorail... but it makes no differnce where i put the files... still nothing...

Comment: @Pekka: I totally agree, Zend_Translate makes gettext usable!

Comment: That's not a tutorial anyways, that's just comments in the PHP manual and they're quite often also wrong. I'd look at gettext in depth or even better look into using Zend_Translate with gettext! It takes so much work off you!

Answer (score 0):

- Is gettext installed?
- Is the PHP module gettext installed?
- Do the .mo files exist? Is Apache allowed to read them?
- Is the desired locale installed?
- Has Apache been restarted?

Comment: i have a wordpress site installed and i can translate it, so i thing everything is installed and up and running..